# My Application does not work after update cordova to 5.4.0 version

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am create a Apache Cordova Application (With Ionic Framework), and after update cordova to 5.4.0 my application doesn't work.

The problem is in my controller MyCtrl.
Indeed I need to wait **$ionicPlatform** be ready in my controller to start, so I used this source code:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $ionicPlatform, $ionicHistory, $cordovaDevice, $cordovaFile, $cordovaFileTransfer, $timeout, $interval, $sce, $ionicPopup) {


    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        alert("It's working !");
    });

})
```

In cordova 5.4.0, this solution does not work.
There are not error, $ionicPlatform.ready is just ignored.

Can you help me to update my application ?
Maybe use $ionicPlatform.ready in controller is not a good idea, but I don't know other solution.

In my controller, I need to use some information like that :

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $ionicPlatform, $ionicHistory, $cordovaDevice, $cordovaFile, $cordovaFileTransfer, $timeout, $interval, $sce, $ionicPopup) {


    $cordovaDevice.getPlatform(); // can work before $ionicPlatform.ready

    cordova.file.documentsDirectory // can work before $ionicPlatform.ready

    window.requestFileSystem // can work before $ionicPlatform.ready

});
```

Than You!

--- edit 2015/11/16 :

Cordova Version : 5.5.3

Ionic Version : 1.7.7

Platform : iOS

IDE : Xcode

Warning : no warning messages

Errors : no errors messages

This is my config.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.test5119111" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" android-versionCode="15" ios-CFBundleVersion="8.4">
  <name>test5</name>
  <!-- <name>テスト</name> -->
  <description>
    テストです。
  </description>
  <author email="kanri@test.com" href="http://test.com/">
    株式会社test
  </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*" />

  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
  <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />

  <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />
  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />

  <feature name="File">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
  </feature>

  <feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
  </feature>

  <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>

  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />

  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />

  <feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device" />
  </feature>

  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/iTunesArtwork" width="512" height="512"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/iTunesArtwork@2x" width="1024" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" height="1136" width="640"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" height="1334" width="750"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" height="2208" width="1242"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" height="1242" width="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" height="1536" width="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" height="768" width="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" height="2048" width="1536"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" height="1024" width="768"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" height="960" width="640"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" height="480" width="320"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="land-xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
</widget>
```

Comment: previous version of Cordova used? Target Platform? Please post your `config.xml`.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, Thank you for your reply. I edit my post

Comment: You have many errors in `config.xml`. You did not answer my questions. Please help me to understand your App. You said "after update (...) doesn't work", what was the previous version of Cordova you were using? What is your target platform? iOS, Android, Windows, Blackberry, other? Are you using an IDE (Android Studio, Visual Studio, Eclipse)?  Are you using the SDK or CLI? If you do not understand what I am saying, ask questions.

Comment: Where can I report bug of cordova plateform ? Is there webpage ?

Comment: Thanks @JesseMonroy650 : Platform is iOS / 
Cordova Version is 5.5.3 / I use Xcode

Comment: "You have many errors in config.xml" ==> I am checking my application just now and there is no errors and no warning on Xcode

Comment: **I'm asking again.** If you don't want help, I can stop now. You said "after update (...) doesn't work", *what was the previous version of Cordova you were using*? Target platfom? *iOS, Android, Windows, Blackberry, other*?

Comment: You said "after update (...) doesn't work", what was the previous version of Cordova you were using? ==> I installed version 5.4.0 of cordova and this application stop to work. So I back to 5.3.3. (In first I was on version 5.3.3)
Target platfom? ===> I said "iOS"

Comment: Okay. thanks for making it clear.

Answer (score 0):

@Officebit,
Thanks for answering questions. Most developers use *Cordova/Phonegap CLi* or *Phonegap Build*. This makes your answer a bit unique.

With your `config.xml`, since you say you are building for `iOS`, I am removing all other things that do not apply (namely, Android and Windows).  You have plenty of errors in your `config.xml`. You should be getting errors for this, but I'm not familiar with your IDE.

Next, you should be getting network error because of Apple's `ATS` system. ATS is blocking your network access. (how to fix in a minute) You should already encountered `ATS`; I'm not 100% sure why you have not encountered `ATS` yet. It could be because your javascript is not firing.

Also, I'm going to assume you are loading all your assets (Javascript, CSS, etc) locally, not from the Internet.

You should do three (3) things.

1. You need to review and make changes to the `config.xml` I am posting.
2. You need to apply the `whitelist` system, which includes the `CSP` and the `ATS`.
3. In your spare time you should read this: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

#### Fixes

**1. `config.xml`** is below.

**2. [HOW TO apply the Cordova/Phonegap the whitelist system](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/the-whitelist-system.md)**
3. In your spare time you should read this: [Top Mistakes by Developers new to Cordova/Phonegap](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md)

- [CSP Examples](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-csp-examples.md) - This goes in your `index.html`.

  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
            content="default-src *; 
                     style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; 
                     script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">`
- [ATS Examples](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/whitelist-ats-examples.md) - This goes in your `Info.plist`.

  `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
       <dict>
       <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
       <true/>
       </dict>`

`Ignore this line. <There is a layout bug. here>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.ionicframework.test5119111" 
    version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    android-versionCode="15" ios-CFBundleVersion="8.4" />
  <name>test5</name>
  <!-- <name>テスト</name> -->
  <description>
    テストです。
  </description>
  <author email="kanri@test.com" href="http://test.com/">
    株式会社test
  </author>
  <content src="index.html"/>

  <!-- These are okay -->
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
  <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true" />
  <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>

  <!-- These paramters are deprecated consider using 
       the plugin [cordova-plugin-splashscreen]
       (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-splashscreen).
       It has different parameters.
   -->
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000"/>

  <!-- 'UIWebViewBounce' is deprecated. Use 'DisallowOverscroll' instead.
       https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/131
       You need to make the change.
   -->
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />

  <!-- I assume this is for the `File` plugin. -->
  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />
  <preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />

  <feature name="File">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFile" />
  </feature>
  <feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
  </feature>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true"/>
  </feature>

  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" height="57"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" height="87"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/iTunesArtwork" width="512" height="512"/>
    <icon src="resources/ios/icon/iTunesArtwork@2x" width="1024" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" height="1136" width="640"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" height="1334" width="750"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" height="2208" width="1242"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" height="1242" width="2208"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" height="1536" width="2048"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" height="768" width="1024"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" height="2048" width="1536"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" height="1024" width="768"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" height="960" width="640"/>
    <splash src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" height="480" width="320"/>
  </platform>
  <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that !
This code doesn't working in cordova 5.4.0 but working on last version (example: cordova 5.3.3): 
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

```
angular.module('PlatformApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('PlatformCtrl', function($scope) {

  ionic.Platform.ready(function(){
    alert("It's ok!");
  });

});
```